# Is it necessary to place @JsonIgnoreProperties to all non-JSON classes in Spring JPA domain?

Tags: java, json, spring

for example I have 20 entity classes in current Spring application, only one need to map to JSON object, so here are two questions:

1. Is it necessary to place `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)` to all other classes?
2. If I choose `org.codehaus.jackson` for JSON handler, is there a chance that jackson will go through all entity classes to try to make a mapping? I have a

   ```
   org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)
   ```

exception thrown but the collection object mentioned in the log has been already marked as `@JsonIgnore`, even the whole class is marked as `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)`. So what could make it like above?

Comment: enjoying the stackoverflow error on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to map a class as a JSON object using Jackson, all the primitives will be fine. However, jackson will try to map any *objects* which are in that object  you're mapping into JSON objects. So any Class that is a field member of the class you're mapping with JSON will either need to be able to be mapped to a JSON (and any object fields it has) or you will need to ignore those object fields in the original class.

Also, if you have any recursive mappings (like a User has a Team, and the Team has a list of users) that can cause an infinite loop. Jackson 2 has some [great solutions](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureObjectIdentity) to help with that.

Comment: "great solution" link broken :(